# XPath for anchor element not in certain parent element?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

Using xpath, how can I get all anchor tags except the ones in italics from the second paragraph? (Question and example has been simplified. Imagine a regular HTML page with multiple `<p>` and `<a>`).

```
<html><body>
    <p>
        <a href="a.html">A</a>
        <b><a href="b.html">B</a></b>
        <i><a href="c.html">C</a></i>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b><a href="e.html">E</a></b>
        <a href="f.html">F</a>
        <i><a href="g.html">G</a></i>
    </p>
</body></html>
```

Should get:

```
<a href="e.html">
<a href="f.html">
```

What I have:

```
root.xpath('//body//p')[1].xpath('a[not(self::i)]')
```

I am only getting:

```
`<a href="f.html">`
```

Comment: Your HTML sample is broken as anchors should have closing tags. Please update your question accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below XPath to get required output:

```
//p[2]//a[not(parent::i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@Andersson commented](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4549554/andersson), it's unclear where your `a` elements are supposed to end.

Assuming that your `a` elements are meant to be self-closing,

```
<html><body>
    <p>
      <a href="a.html"/>
      <b><a href="b.html"/></b>
      <i><a href="c.html"/></i>
    </p>
    <p>
      <b><a href="e.html"/></b>
      <a href="f.html"/>
      <i><a href="g.html"/></i>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then this XPath,

```
/html/body/p[2]//a[not(parent::i)]
```

selects all of the `a` descendents of the second paragraph whose parent is not an `i` element:

```
<a href="e.html"/>
<a href="f.html"/>
```

Credit: Thanks to @Andersson for a correction.  Please upvote [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49346236/290085).  Thanks.